# Google apps script error: "You do not have permission to call protect"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-custom-function

I'm trying out my first Google Sheets Apps Script. I'm trying to make a custom function (via a bound script) that will check if the cell it's in is protected. If it is protected, it should change the cell's value to (for now at least) the protection type.

I can successfully run the simple demo script in the docs:

```
function DOUBLE(input) {
  return input * 2;
}
```

But when calling Range::protect, I can an error

```
"You do not have permission to call protect"
```

Here's the function

```
function isProtected() {
 var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
 var protection = range.protect();
 return protection.getProtectionType();
}
```

I also get the same permissions error with some other functions, e.g. `Session.getEffectiveUser()`.
I figured that since this is a bound custom function and I'm the (only) sheet owner, I'd be able to call these methods. What am I missing? Thanks.

I've tried copy-pasting the script into the script editor of a new sheet, since some posts have had luck with that, but no luck for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Custom function run anonymously so the implicit consequence is that **they can not do anything that requires authorization**.

Changing a `range protection` requires an authorization , that's why you can't use it and get the message you get...

Same situation for `getEffectiveUser()`, it requires an authorization too.

[Reference in docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced) :

> Unlike most other types of Apps Scripts, custom functions never ask
>   users to authorize access to personal data. Consequently, they can
>   only call services that do not have access to personal data

Comment: Thanks! I didn't read deeply enough into the docs, obviously. I'll try another approach to get what I need, something that's bound to the sheet and won't require a user to load an add-on.